# How can I run a NSTask in the background and show the results in a modal NSWindow while running

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nstask

I would like to execute a command with NSTask, and be able to see the progress in a modal window. For example if I execute 'ls -R /' i would like to see the chunks appearing in a NSTextView.

I came up with the following, and everything works fine, except the update part. The task get executed (with the spinning beachbal) and when it is finished i see the result appear in the textview.

```cs
@interface ICA_RunWindowController ()

@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTextView* textResult;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSButton* buttonAbort;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSButton* buttonOK;

- (IBAction) doOK:(id) sender;
- (IBAction) doAbort:(id) sender;

@end

@implementation ICA_RunWindowController {
  NSTask * executionTask;
  id taskObserver;
  NSFileHandle * errorFile;
  id errorObserver;
  NSFileHandle * outputFile;
  id outputObserver;
  }

@synthesize textResult,buttonAbort,buttonOK;  

- (IBAction)doOK:(id)sender {
  [[self window] close];
  [NSApp stopModal];
  }

- (IBAction)doAbort:(id)sender {
  [executionTask terminate];
  }

- (void) taskCompleted {
NSLog(@"Task completed");
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:taskObserver];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:errorObserver];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:outputObserver];
  [self outputAvailable];
  [self errorAvailable];
  executionTask = nil;
  [buttonAbort setEnabled:NO];
  [buttonOK setEnabled:YES];
  }


- (void) appendText:(NSString *) text inColor:(NSColor *) textColor {
  NSDictionary * makeUp = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:textColor forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
  NSAttributedString * extraText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:makeUp];
  [textResult setEditable:YES];
  [textResult setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange([[textResult textStorage] length], 0)];
  [textResult insertText:extraText];
  [textResult setEditable:NO];
  [textResult display];
  }

- (void) outputAvailable {
  NSData * someData = [outputFile readDataToEndOfFile];
  if ([someData length] > 0) {
NSLog(@"output Available");
    NSString * someText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:someData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self appendText:someText inColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
    }
  }

- (void) errorAvailable {
  NSData * someData = [errorFile readDataToEndOfFile];
  if ([someData length] > 0) {
NSLog(@"Error Available");
    NSString * someText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:someData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self appendText:someText inColor:[NSColor redColor]];
    }
  }

- (void) runCommand:(NSString *) command {
// make sure all views are initialized
  [self showWindow:[self window]];
// some convience vars
  NSArray * runLoopModes = @[NSDefaultRunLoopMode, NSRunLoopCommonModes];
  NSNotificationCenter * defCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
// create an task
  executionTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
// fill the parameters for the task
  [executionTask setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];
  [executionTask setArguments:@[@"-c",command]];
// create an observer for Termination
  taskObserver = [defCenter addObserverForName:NSTaskDidTerminateNotification
                                        object:executionTask 
                                         queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                    usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) 
    {
      [self taskCompleted];        
      }
    ];

// Create a pipe and a filehandle for reading errors
  NSPipe * error = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
  [executionTask setStandardError:error];
  errorFile = [error fileHandleForReading];
  errorObserver = [defCenter addObserverForName:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification
                                         object:errorFile 
                                          queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                     usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) 
    {
      [self errorAvailable];        
      [errorFile waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotifyForModes:runLoopModes];
      }
    ];
  [errorFile waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotifyForModes:runLoopModes];

// Create a pipe and a filehandle for reading output
  NSPipe * output = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
  [executionTask setStandardOutput:output];
  outputFile = [output fileHandleForReading];
  outputObserver = [defCenter addObserverForName:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification
                                          object:outputFile 
                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                      usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) 
    {
      [self outputAvailable];        
      [outputFile waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotifyForModes:runLoopModes];
      }
    ];
  [outputFile waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotifyForModes:runLoopModes];

// start task
  [executionTask launch];

// show our window as modal
  [NSApp runModalForWindow:[self window]];
  }
```

My question: Is it possible to update the output while the task is running? And, if yes, how could I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A modal window runs the run loop in `NSModalPanelRunLoopMode`, so you need to add that to your `runLoopModes`.

You should not be getting the spinning beach ball. The cause is that you're calling `-readDataToEndOfFile` in your `-outputAvailable` and `-errorAvailable` methods. Given that you're using `-waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotifyForModes:`, you would use the `-availableData` method to get what data is available without blocking.

Alternatively, you could use `-readInBackgroundAndNotifyForModes:`, monitor the `NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification` notification, and, in your handler, obtain the data from the notification object using `[[note userInfo] objectForKey:NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem]`. In other words, let `NSFileHandle` do the work of reading the data for you.

Either way, though, once you get the end-of-file indicator (an empty `NSData`), you should not re-issue the `...InBackgroundAndNotifyForModes:` call. If you do, you'll busy-spin as it keeps feeding you the same end-of-file indicator over and over.

It shouldn't be necessary to manually `-display` your text view. Once you fix the blocking calls that were causing the spinning color wheel cursor, that will also allow the normal window updating to happen automatically.

Comment: Thanks, everything works as desired now.

I changed the -..Available methods to

Comment: - (BOOL) outputAvailable {
      NSData * someData = [outputFile availableData];
      if ([someData length] > 0) {
        NSString * someText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:someData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [self appendText:someText inColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
        return YES;
        }
      return NO;  
      }

that way i can control the re-issue of the waitFor... call

    if ([self outputAvailable])     
      [outputFile waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotifyForModes:runLoopModes];